# How to get a max value from graph which is shockwave flash

Tags: python, html, json, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a script using selenium webdriver with python where I need to take a highest values from a Flash-based graph and some values are visible when I hover at any point on this graph.

[image]

When I checked network traffic from inspect element I got this link :

> getStatsData?https://my.xxxx.com/monitor/getStatsData?graphTypeId=0&segTypeId=1&site1Id=303602&site2Id=All&directionId=0&additionalInfo=&applicationIdList=All&startTime=1456304821&endTime=1456391221

When clicked, it opens in new page with lot of JSON values.I think these values are used to build graph within SWF file. But I am not able to get that url from Selenium

So is there a way I can get a maximum value out of this graph in Selenium webdriver with Python?

Comment: My edit was to improve question readability. That html code for embedding SWF app in webpage is irrelevant to the question, The AS3 code itself **inside that SWF app** is what's getting required JSON. More useful would be **actual working links** to see problem in action. That JSON url looks "time protected" and must be freshly generated per request, usually by PHP file that echos the JSON back. You can check **network tab** for such, but since no links for us volunteering helpers, well good luck

Comment: Well i understand your concern its me who was not able to explain it previously so i modified it .Sorry about link but i am bound to company's rules and confidentiality thing . And yes that url is freshly generated thats why i wanted something to catch that url when page loads that time these uls are generated to get JSON data and can be seen in Network tab . As we cannot interact with SWF app in selenium webdriver so i was trying to get the JSON values itself .

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
import json

json_str = (
    '{"ResJSON":{"timeseries":{"unit":["secs","bps","bps","bps"],'
    '"columns":["timestamp","Total","Optimized","Pass-Through"],'
    '"values":[[1456304820,1350.9333,1290.8000,60.1333],'
    '[1456304880,1252.9333,1217.0667,35.8667],'
    '[1456304899, 1600, 1570, 30]]}}}')

data = json.loads(json_str)

chart_values = [v[1] for v in data['ResJSON']['timeseries']['values']]
max_value = max(chart_values)
print('Maximum value:', max_value)
```

I am extracting `Total` column from `values` table to `chart_values` list and getting maximum value from it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Python but try something like this as a starting point...

```
import json

myData  = json.loads(your_JSON_string)

value_list = myData['ResJSON']['timeseries']['values']

print "Maximum Value is : ", max(value_list)
```

Comment: thanks for your response but i am not able to get that json values from web as it is not straight url which can be seen by user. It is visible after doing inspect element and clicking on network tab.

Comment: Yeah? On that **network tab** was there a PHP file involved too? I've seen that type of URL before. Youtube protects direct links to video files in the same way.

Comment: No i don't see any PHP file in network tab .But i do see some jquery